# ZK framework and mobile

Tags: android, ios, mobile, web-applications, zk

I'm going to create a website with very rich functionality to help people manage their quite specific resources. I decided to use ZK framework for this, but I also want to create a native Android and iOs apps later. Is it possible with ZK to provide something like a REST API to use in these apps? I dont want to use ZK mobile web version of site.

Answer (score 0):

In classical ZK you have your components both in the server side (servlet container) and in the browser, and an AJAX communications inbetween. It is something like a JS component framework + REST + you server side REST-specific code.

A propose to use the 3-layer architecture with a Data Access Layer, a Business Logis Layer and a Presentation Layer. Only the Presentation Layer is different for ZK, Android and iOS:

- For ZK you will have ZUL pages and Controllers.
- For Android and iOS you will have a very this Servie Layer where the Use Cases of your app will be translated between the Business Logic Interface and the REST calls. And of course, all presentational logic (such like disable Submit till user not yet confirmed Terms of Usage) will be done in the Android/iOS app.

Of course, use ZK only if you plan to run the first two layers and the REST Sevices in a Java servlet container.